# HTML Parsing in iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, webview

I want to retrieve html data from database. I used this code for parsing,

```
  -(NSString *)MultipleCharactersHTML:(NSString *)url
 {
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//  NSLog(@"return string %@",returnString);
returnString=[returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
returnString=[returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"<" withString:@"<"];
returnString=[returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">\"" withString:@">"];
NSError *err = nil;
// NSLog(@"return string replaced %@",returnString);

//    NSMutableArray *search = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
//  NSLog(@"search response %@",search);
return returnString;
 }
```

But I was not able to retrieve data...

I am going to set this data as htmlstring for my webview...Anyone please guide me..

Data from database will be in this format...

```
  <div class="layout-content-row content-header " style="display: inline-block; margin: 36px 0px 23px; height: 30px; padding: 0px 0px 10px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);"><div class="layout-content-col span-9" style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; width: 520px; height: 1px;"><h1 itemprop="name" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 34px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 30px; width: 700px;">Creative Vision</h1></div><div class="paging-links layout-content-col span-4" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; position: relative; height: 30px; width: 220px;"><a href="http://developer.android.com/design/index.html" class="prev-page-link" zh-tw-lang="&#19978;&#19968;&#22530;&#35506;" zh-cn-lang="&#19978;&#19968;&#35838;" ru-lang="&#1055;&#1088;&#1077;&#1076;&#1099;&#1076;&#1091;&#1097;&#1080;&#1081;" ko-lang="&#51060;&#51204;" ja-lang="&#21069;&#12408;" es-lang="Anterior" style="position: absolute; color: rgb(37, 138, 175); text-transform: uppercase; left: -15px;">PREVIOUS</a><a href="http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html" class="next-page-link" zh-tw-lang="&#19979;&#19968;&#22530;&#35506;" zh-cn-lang="&#19979;&#19968;&#35838;" ru-lang="&#1057;&#1083;&#1077;&#1076;&#1091;&#1102;&#1097;&#1080;&#1081;" ko-lang="&#45796;&#51020;" ja-lang="&#27425;&#12408;" es-lang="Siguiente" style="position: absolute; color: rgb(37, 138, 175); text-transform: uppercase; right: 0px;">NEXT</a></div></div><span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);"></span><div id="jd-content" style="height: 790px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);"><div class="jd-descr" itemprop="articleBody" style="height: 725px;"><img src="http://developer.android.com/design/media/creative_vision_main.png" style="max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;"><div class="vspace size-1" style="height: 10px;"> </div><p itemprop="description" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Starting with Ice Cream Sandwich, we focused the design of Android around these three overarching goals, which apply to our core apps as well as the system at large. As you work with Android, consider these goals.</p><div class="vspace size-1" style="height: 10px;"> </div><div class="layout-content-row" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="layout-content-col span-4" style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; width: 220px;"><h4 style="line-height: 21px; margin: 0px 0px 12px;">Enchant me</h4><p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Beauty is more than skin deep. Android apps are sleek and aesthetically pleasing on multiple levels. Transitions are fast and clear; layout and typography are crisp and meaningful. App icons are works of art in their own right. Just like a well-made tool, your app should strive to combine beauty, simplicity and purpose to create a magical experience that is effortless and powerful.</p></div><div class="layout-content-col span-5" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; width: 280px;"><h4 style="line-height: 21px; margin: 0px 0px 12px;">Simplify my life</h4><p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Android apps make life easier and are easy to understand. When people use your app for the first time, they should intuitively grasp the most important features. The design work doesn't stop at the first use, though. Android apps remove ongoing chores like file management and syncing. Simple tasks never require complex procedures, and complex tasks are tailored to the human hand and mind. People of all ages and cultures feel firmly in control, and are never overwhelmed by too many choices or irrelevant flash.</p></div><div class="layout-content-col span-4" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; width: 220px;"><h4 style="line-height: 21px; margin: 0px 0px 12px;">Make me amazing</h4><p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">It's not enough to make an app that is easy to use. Android apps empower people to try new things and to use apps in inventive new ways. Android lets people combine applications into new workflows through multitasking, notifications, and sharing across apps. At the same time, your app should feel personal, giving people access to superb technology with clarity and grace.</p></div></div></div><div class="content-footer layout-content-row" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; width: 760px;"><div class="paging-links layout-content-col col-10" style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; position: relative; height: 30px; display: inline; margin-right: 10px; width: 580px;"><a href="http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html" class="next-page-link" zh-tw-lang="&#19979;&#19968;&#22530;&#35506;" zh-cn-lang="&#19979;&#19968;&#35838;" ru-lang="&#1057;&#1083;&#1077;&#1076;&#1091;&#1102;&#1097;&#1080;&#1081;" ko-lang="&#45796;&#51020;" ja-lang="&#27425;&#12408;" es-lang="Siguiente" style="position: absolute; color: rgb(37, 138, 175); text-transform: uppercase; right: 0px; left: 0px;">NEXT: DESIGN PRINCIPLES</a></div></div></div>
```

Comment: could u tell me wats wrong in my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... As Harshini Nerella said , you can use UIWebView to load tags directly from database . And make sure you are saving data's in  database with correct format . Don't encode the retrieved values in PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

If the response you are getting is htmlstring, then you can set that html string directly to UIWebView instance.

```
 UIWebView *eventInfoWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, self.view.frame.size.width, eventInfoSV.frame.size.height-130)];
 [eventInfoWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ]; this line not converting data into string...

Answer (score 0):

use third party classes to parse the HTML code to parse each and every tags particularly..

Exaples :

https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser